# How to transition on hover/unhover, but not on class change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of tabs that can be selected.  When I set the transition on the tab `span` itself, and hover over the `span`, it will transition its background color when hovering over, and when hovering off.  That's the behaviour I want so far.  However, I also have some code that changes the active tab by applying a class to a certain tab.  I don't want this to transition - the active tab should change highlighting immediately.

How can I set up the CSS so that changing the active tab by applying (and removing) an "active" class won't transition the background color, but hovering the mouse cursor over will?

Here is my HTML/CSS:

```css
.tabGroup {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 3px;
border: 1px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
border-radius: 15px;
}

.tabGroup li {
flex-grow: 1;
list-style: none;
}

.tabGroup li span {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
color: hsla(210, 2%, 81%, 0.7);
text-decoration: none;

transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 2s ease-in-out;
}

.tabGroup li span:hover {
color: rgb(233, 236, 239);
background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}

.tabGroup li span.active {
color: rgb(233, 236, 239);
background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabGroup">
<li>
    <span>Link</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Facebook</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Twitter</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Pinterest</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Telegram</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: without your actual code we cannot really do much. Kindly provide us a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together basic Javascript to add active on the clicking on a button to demo the solution.

Simply adding **transition: none** to **.tabGroup li span.active** will disable the transaction if active is added to the span.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let test = document.querySelector("#test span");
  test.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
.tabGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tabGroup li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabGroup li span {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: hsla(210, 2%, 81%, 0.7);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 2s ease-in-out;
}

.tabGroup li span:hover {
  color: rgb(233, 236, 239);
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}

.tabGroup li span.active {
  color: rgb(233, 236, 239);
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  transition: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabGroup">
  <li id="test">
    <span>Link</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Facebook</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Twitter</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Pinterest</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Telegram</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<button class="btn">Add active</button>
```